# Why Are My Intraday Table Timestamps Set In The Future When I Query Them?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

The table named events_intraday_YYYYMMDD is the intraday table because it accumulates data throughout the day, as new events are passed through Google Analytics 4.

It’s different from the daily tables (events_YYYYMMDD) as those are exported once per day in bulk.

As intraday collects the data from “today” in realtime, you first need to agree with Google BigQuery on what “today” refers to. BigQuery can’t guess what timezone you want to query, which is why the default UNIX timestamp format of the event_timestamp column in BigQuery is always in UTC time.

We know that time differences may be due to the zone, but when we look at the data, there are month and year differences. How is this possible?

[image]

There may be a time difference in the intraday table due to the zone, but there should not be a month and year difference. Why could this be the case and how can I solve it?